# iOS Swift : Parse remote push notification does NOT go to all users

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I have two devices (my colleague's and mine).  He is in Chicago and I am here in DC.  Both are not connected to any computer.  When I send a push from Parse's remote push ( https://www.parse.com/apps/"your app name here "/push_notifications ), only my device receives the notification.

When I select to send to ALL devices, only my device receives the notification.

When I select to send only to his device, it says it will be sent to ONE device:

[image]
He does not receive the notification and in the Push status window, it says "Pushes Sent - 0".
[image]

I know Parse recognizes his user pointer because if you enter an invalid user pointer, you "will be sent to 0 devices"

[image: invalid user pointer]

We both are working on the same build and have the exact same code. Are there potentially different settings outside of the project?  Yes, he has authorized notifications for the app.

Also, additional verification:  Here is a screenshot of my user table.
[image]

And here is the related row in the Installation table:

[image]

Parse's condition recognizes his device:

[image]

Comment: Do you see his installation in the parse db?

Comment: Maybe he receives it but doesn't see it. Has he checked the Notification Center?

Comment: Asking about notification center.  I just checked the Installation table and he does have a row.

Comment: Because if it says, it is sent to one device, if you choose his installation, it should work.

Comment: The push count when sent to his device = 0.  But as you can see from the images I just uploaded he has an installation row that matches his user objectId.

Comment: Hm okay. I'm a bit confused because you've written in your question: "When I select to send only to his device, it says it will be sent to ONE device:".

Comment: Please see most recent image.  It does say it "WILL" be sent to his objectId but it never is sent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71451/discussion-between-christian-woerz-and-lostinthebits).

Comment: Is there a solution to this that was determined via the chat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue a long time ago. The cause of that could be non-valid/corrupt deviceTokens.

It helped In my case to uninstall the app and to delete the corrupt installation from the Parse database. Then I've had to re-install the app on the device again. That way a new devicetoken gets generated and a new installation gets added to the parse database.

Comment: I have been looking for a solution for a day now. This was really helpful.